# Error using ASP.NET Dynamic Data Filtering with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I have just added the [Dynamic Data Filtering](http://dynamicdatafiltering.codeplex.com/) library to an Entity Framework based Dynamic Data web *application*, but on trying to access List.aspx, I get the following error.  Is there anything I can do about this on .NET 4?

```
The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that problem one without  Dynamic Data Filtering library.

I solved it by using the project template: *dynamic data entities web application*.

---

I found the solution on the page

> http://blog.davidyack.com/journal/2008/5/21/dynamic-data-choosing-the-right-template.html

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this error too.  Just add an OrderBy before the Skip in your query, just like it says.